# na.pass in nlme (mixed models) leads to contrary results

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, missing-data

UPDATE - One of the authors of the nlme package wrote the following: 
Internally the nlme package uses compiled code such as LAPACK which does not have provision for missing values. The results when using na.pass will be unpredictable and invalid.

I am calculating mixed models (linear growth models) with the `nlme` package in R for a sample with N = 45 and 10 time points measuring change in health over time. Health (outcome) is measured at all time points, but the predictors are only measured at one time point. I have some missing values in the predictors (10 people have missing values in the predictors) so I decided to use `na.action = na.pass` to include all persons. However, the results vary immensely when I conduct small changes that should not change a lot. 
My basic function is:

```
lgm1 <- lme(health ~ predictor*time, data=data1, random= ~time | id, na.action = na.pass,
            correlation = corAR1())
```

With this function, the predictor and the `predictor * time` interaction are significant. However, when I change the order of the predictors (now: `time * predictor`), the result is completely different, there is not even a hint of significance in the predictor, only the interaction stays the same. 
When I replace `na.pass` with `na.omit`, the result is completely different as well (n.s. for all). At least, with `na.omit`, the order of the predictors doesn't change the result anymore.

Does anybody know why this happens and how I can deal with it in a good way? What does `na.pass` do? I am not sure how to deal with this finding as the differences are huge and I don't want to draw the wrong conclusions from the data.

Comment: As for the order of the predictors this may help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14522/variable-order-and-accounted-variability-in-linear-mixed-effects-modeling Regarding the difference of `na.pass` and `na.omit` look in the R help file: `?na.pass`. You probably want `na.exclude`?

Comment: Thank you for this link, this is very helpful! I am however still not sure what na.pass does when using it in the lme function. R help says: "na.pass returns the object unchanged" - What does this mean for the lme function? It seems to include the cases with missings, but I don't understand how. The way it deals with the missings seems to have a huge impact on the result.

Comment: UPDATE - One of the authors of the nlme package wrote the following: Internally the nlme package uses compiled code such as LAPACK which does not have provision for missing values. The results when using na.pass will be unpredictable and invalid.